# Set a NSTextField to blank with a NumberFormatter

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield, number-formatting

I want to blank a NSTextField that has a IB Number Formatter associated with it, the formatter restricts it to positive integers.

It didn't occur to me before I did it but predictably setString:@"" returns

```
-[NSTextField setString:]: unrecognized selector
```

Is this possible and what method would I use to do it?

Thanks!

Graham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for setStringValue: